# Gratis app with ads, or for a fee without ads

Tags: android, upload, google-play

I have developed my first android application and I plan to upload it free of charge, However I am thinking to do add a feature in the future for a little amount of fees and make the game ads free. So my question is how to have an app that is free but have a feature that require money to be available, does it mean I need to have 2 apps (one free and one isnt) in the market and whenever I want to update the game I need to update both of them. I hope I have clarified my question because I dont know how to explain it more.

Ah one more thing, how long does the app take to be available in the market?!

Thanks for your time and consideration, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [In app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)

As it says:

> In-app Billing is a Google Play service that lets you sell digital
>   content from inside your applications. You can use the service to sell
>   a wide range of content, including downloadable content such as media
>   files or photos, virtual content such as game levels or potions,
>   premium services and features, and more. You can use In-app Billing to
>   sell products as

Once you press publish your app should be available in about 30 minutes. However beware of one thing, once you release a free app you can't change it to a paid app so in-app billing would be your only way of achieving your goal without making separate app.

Answer (score 2):

you could use in app billing to enable these features and still have the app free.

the app itself can take a couple hours to be visible on the play store